# sscanf incompatible pointer types

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

So I am attempting to read in all the components of a line using the sscanf function like this:

```
char *R1;
char *R2;
int immediate;
char mnemonic[6];
FILE *input = fopen("file.txt","r");
...
sscanf(input, "%s %s %s %d", mnemonic, R1, R2, immediate);
```

When I compile, I am given the following warning:

```
Warning: passing argument 1 pf 'sscanf' from incompatible pointer type note: expected const char * restrict but argument is of type 'struct FILE *'
```

I suspect that this warning is the reason my code is failing to execute as intended, could someone please try to explain what the problem could be?

Comment: The error message does not correspond to the line of code you posted. The error message mentions a variable `pf`, which is not in the `sscanf` line.

Comment: Are you passing a `FILE*` as the first arg to `sscanf()` ? Shouldn't it be a `char*` or `fscanf()`?

Comment: Not all of them it didn't....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to read from a `FILE*`, you want to use`fscanf`, not `sscanf`.  The latter scans from a string (`char *`).

Also, you need to pass a corresponding pointer-to-int for `%d`, otherwise `fscanf` cannot modify the integer.

Also, you're passing uninitialized `char*`s - `fscanf` is going to try to write your strings to some undefined address. You need to give them storage like you did for `mnemonic`.

Finally, whenever you're using `%s`, you should explicitly tell it the size of your buffer. Otherwise you can easily overflow it.

```
char R1[6];
char R2[6];
int immediate;
char mnemonic[6];
FILE *input = fopen("file.txt","r");
...
if (fscanf(input,
    "%6s %6s %6s %d", mnemonic, R1, R2, &immediate) != 4) {
    // bad things happened
```